# Searching for \n\n in a returned message

Tags: c, binaryfiles

I'm writing a program that is essentially emulating the linux GET command, which will return a msg that contains a file and the header separated by \n\n inside the message. The only thing is I'm not sure how to search the returned string and find this message, because \n signifies that a string has ended. If anyone can help lead me on the correct path that would be awesome.

Comment: Are you sure it's `\n\n` and not `\r\n`?

Comment: I'm just going by what the professor shared with us, he said it was \n\n, but it might be \r\n, I'm just not sure how to read those characters in a binary file, or do a comparison with them.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames \n\n is also a common used pattern, for example in the return of a GET HTTP statement

Comment: Ok, so it is \n\n that I'm looking for. How to I read that in a returned message? Because that is exactly what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, assuming you are talking about zero terminated strings (the norm), `\0` (i.e. the `NUL` character, i.e. a zero) indicates a string has ended, not `\n`.

You can search for two `\n` using the `strstr` function. From the man page:

```
   #include <string.h>

   char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
```

So something like:

```
char *found;
found = strstr (string_to_search, "\n\n");
```

Comment: The thing is, this should be a binary message that I am comparing, which means that there is a chance it could contain the value for \0, which would break this process would it not?

Comment: Sure, in which case use `memchr` and check that the next character is also `\n`.